# .chm files in a VM won't display

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, chm

I'm running Win7 in Parallels on a MacBook Pro. HTML help files (.chm) will not open, I get the "Navigation to the webpage was canceled" message. The files are not tagged as blocked in properties.

I've seen (but not tried) some registry entries that purport to solve the issue on a file-by-file or folder basis. I'm hoping for a more global solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows may be regarding the location of the .chm files as being on a network drive. There's a link to a program called HHReg on this page: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/devdocs/thread/ef2b95e0-4198-4e1a-b876-314a23348b5e

Comment: I had read that. I tried HHReg and it changed the reaction. The help file now opens, but the page is blank.

Comment: The help compiler still displays the error message. When the program that uses the file opens it, page is blank. Double clicking on the file directly opens it normally.

Comment: Can you try the same actions in Windows 7 not running in a VM? I'm not familiar with Parallels, but if it integrates the Windows desktop with the Mac desktop, maybe your file(s) are actually in the Mac environment, so could you make a subdirectory of C:\ to hold the files you're working with?

Comment: I made a folder 'C:\Help\' and put the .chm there, and it opened correctly. The same app in 'Program files(x86)\MyApp crashes when help is called. Another app in Program Files(x86) works correctly. I think you're on the right track, but this problem makes it very difficult to get any programming done. If a user has the same setup, it's not good.

Comment: The folder Win is displaying as "Documents" was \\psf\home\Documents. I moved all the relevant files to "C:\Users\Mikey\My Documents" and life is good again.

Answer (score 1):

After a while trying to fix this problem i noticed that my .chm files would not open if inside a folder (or full path) that contains the character #

I'm using Windows 7

Comment: My issue was Win 7, in a VM, saw the drive the .chm was on as a networked drive.